# Why is there no way to vote on a post in the "Review Low Quality Posts" review queue?

Tags: feature-request

In the "low quality" review queue:

[image]

Most of the time what I really want to be doing is *downvote* the answer. Look specifically at [this example](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/27936/is-it-normal-for-an-advisor-to-expect-80-hour-workweeks-from-phd-students-and/35200#35200). The post is (sorry to the poster) just bad. I don't want to edit it and none of the **Delete** reasons applies. However, I definitely want to downvote it. There is no button that actually lets me do that. What I need to do is press **Looks Ok** (which it doesn't), click the tiny **Link** button on the right, and downvote outside of the review queue.

This is the case for me for 2 out of 3 entries in this queue. I would like to see buttons for up- and downvoting here on the level of **Edit** and **Delete**.

Comment: See [this main meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191276/upvoting-on-low-quality-posts-in-review-tasks)

Answer (score 2):

This is how we've been explained to interpret stuff in our queues on Stack Overflow, which gets a much higher volume of questions. The goal is to check whether the answer passes the smell test as an answer, not whether it holds water as an answer.

[Here's an example of usage from Stack Overflow over the use of "Looks Okay".](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266428/low-quality-review-queue-meaning-of-looks-ok)

*Looks Okay* does not mean *Is Correct*.

Consider the following example question:

> What is 1 + 1?

And the example answers, with the correct(ish) response in parentheses

- Two (Looks Okay)
- 1.99999 (Looks Okay)
- I like turtles! (Not an Answer)
- example.com (Link-only Answer)
- Has anyone figured it out? (Not an Answer)

---

As awkward as it may seem, the second answer, 1.99999, based on what the LQPRQ is looking for, should be marked as "Looks Okay." The answer may be categorically *wrong* (in which case you would downvote it), but the goal of the queue itself is to get rid of content which do not meet the guidelines to be considered an answer.

So long as it is an attempt at an answer, the correct action we're supposed to do is mark it as "Looks Okay" from an Answer perspective.

After that, we can go to the page and downvote, comment that this is wrong, unsafe, insane, etc.

Answers that get downvoted because they are wrong and answers that get deleted because they are not answers fall in different buckets.

Comment: I understand. My problem is that the majority of answers in this queue on academia.SE seem to be case two, which needs to be handled outside the review interface currently (not particularly cool).

Comment: @xLeitix That's unfortunately the price of a system where subjective answers are encouraged. There's a few right ways to do most things on most Stacks, but on this one, a question with a single answer is normally pretty trivial.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Stack Exchange-wide "feature," which I imagine would have to be implemented at that level, rather than just on Academia.SE.